# Rounding down inside an AddEventListener

Tags: javascript, rounding

Quick Question, I am creating a unit converter and I am trying to round down to 3 decimal places so I don't get a bunch of lingering numbers at the end of my calculation.

I am currently using addEventListeners, I have tried to add `.toFixed()` everywhere and I cannot seem to find a solution to my dilemma.

Here is an example of my code:

```js
convertBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    let baseValue = inputEl.value;
    massEl.textContent = `${baseValue} Kilos = ${baseValue * kiloToPound.toFixed(3)} Pounds ||
                          ${baseValue} Pounds = ${baseValue * poundToKilo.toFixed(3)} Kilos`
})
```

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: `(baseValue * kiloToPound).toFixed(3)`

Comment: please accept indev's answer if it solves your problem

Comment: @Normal which is just the same as my comment. This is not a question to be answered It should be voted to be closed as typo-type and deleted

Answer (score 1):

Add parentheses to your .ToFixed() calls:

```js
convertBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    let baseValue = inputEl.value;
    massEl.textContent = `${baseValue} Kilos = ${(baseValue * kiloToPound).toFixed(3)} Pounds ||
                          ${baseValue} Pounds = ${(baseValue * poundToKilo).toFixed(3)} Kilos`
})
```

Comment: OMG THANK YOU, WOW WOW WOW....

Lesson learned on this one, man alive I was going wonky trying to solve WOW

Comment: Please do not answer typo-type questions - especially not with something that was already commented. The question should be closed and deleted